# Django how to avoid hitting database again

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to avoid hitting database when calling Model's function on template?

in my views:

```
class ContractListView(FilterView):
    model = Contract
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Contract.objects.prefetch_related('payments')
        return qs
```

in my template Im calling Contract model's function `payment_status`.

model:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def payment_status(self):   
        ...

        payments = self.payments.values_list('payment_date', flat=True) # it is hitting database again

        return True if first in payments else False
```

When I see sql queries in `debug_toolbar` prefetch_related is working fine but every row is repeating the query again. How can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this-

```
payments = [payment_obj.payment_date for payment_obj in self.payments.all()]
```